# Read 2D Array of String in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a 2D array of chars from some input on the keyboard.My main problem is that I don't know what I am doing wrong but I am able to get a result when I go above the length of the array. For example if I have a n x n matrix, i can print the value x[0][n] or x[0][n+1]. I just want to know what am I doing wrong as I should get an error as I am trying to go over the bound of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *safeMalloc(int n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc(%d) failed. Out of memory?\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

char ** readMatrix(int m){
    char **arr = safeMalloc(m*sizeof(char *));
    int row;
    for (row=0; row < m; row++) {
        arr[row] = safeMalloc(m*sizeof(char));
    }
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            scanf(" %c",&arr[i][j]);;
        }
        getchar();
    }

    return arr;
}

void printNumber(char **arr,int m){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%c", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char** arr;
    arr=readMatrix(n);
    printf("%c\n",arr[0][8]);
    printNumber(arr,n);
}
```

For example :

```
8
****....
****....
****....
****....
........
........
........
........
```

It prints the array as I expected but I can still get some funny char if I go over the bound 8.

Comment: If you entered `8` then `arr[0][8]` is out of bounds. "I have a n x n matrix, i can print the value `x[0][n]` or `x[0][n+1]`." No, you can't print either without *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: I know that I should't be able to get a character when i am trying to print something that is out of bounds But still I am able to do so .I get some funny char instead of an out of bound error

Comment: As I wrote, it is *undefined behaviour*. So stop wasting your time trying to explain the **funny character**. You might be able to overflow to the next line if the array really was a 2D array, but it isn't. It is a 1-D array of 1-D array pointers.

Comment: If you create a 8x8 matrix, why are you trying to get the 9th element of line 1?

Comment: So you are saying that I shouldn't expect an out of bound error but some undefined behavior when I am printing that out of bound value?

Comment: C does not have "an out of bound error".

Comment: Aha. Now I understand . I thought that I was  allocating more memory than I should (although I couldn't see why as I just use the length ). Thanks

Comment: @AndreiMădălinOancă - I must admit that it is refreshing to get a question, with well-formatted code, a good attempt at a clear problem description and a reasonable explanation regarding where your confusion arises. (remember all arrays are **zero** indexed, e.g. for `n=8` valid indexes are `0-7`)

Comment: Note : `void *safeMalloc(int n)` has 2 corner functional problems: type should be `size_t`, not `int` and `safeMalloc(0)` should not cause the `exit()`.   `void *safeMalloc(size_t n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL && n > 0) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since C doesn't check array boundaries thats why you are not getting error but getting funny characters by accessing memory past the end of the array.

Comment: That's rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: "C doesn't check array boundaries" --> maybe or maybe not.  A C compilation _may_ check boundaries and even have a "an out of bound error".   Out of bounds access is undefined behavior (UB).